# Returning a reference to a local/temprorary object without causing a memory leak?

Tags: c++, overlap, allegro

I realize this is wrong (my compiler says so!):

```
Rectangle& Rectangle::Overlap(const Rectangle& rectangle) {

    Point topLeft(__max(this->GetVerticies()[0]->GetX(), rectangle.GetVerticies()[0]->GetX()) - __min(this->GetVerticies()[0]->GetX() + this->GetWidth(), rectangle.GetVerticies()[0]->GetX() + rectangle.GetWidth()), 
                 (__max(this->GetVerticies()[0]->GetY(), rectangle.GetVerticies()[0]->GetY()) - __min(this->GetVerticies()[0]->GetY() + this->GetHeight(), rectangle.GetVerticies()[0]->GetY() + rectangle.GetHeight())));

    Point bottomRight(__min(this->GetVerticies()[0]->GetX() + this->GetWidth(), rectangle.GetVerticies()[0]->GetX() + rectangle.GetWidth()), topLeft.GetY() + __max(this->GetVerticies()[0]->GetY() + this->GetHeight(), rectangle.GetVerticies()[0]->GetY() + rectangle.GetHeight()));

    return Rectangle(topLeft, bottomRight);
}
```

What would be the correct way to return the calculated rectangle without causing a memory leak? Defining the rectangle as Rectangle* result = new Rectangle(topLeft, bottomRight) then returning the dereferenced pointer works but just seems...wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: This isn't a memory leak. On the contrary, you are freeing memory (a temporary variable that is created when you call Rectangle() constructor) before you ever get a chance to actually access it. See hkasier's answer for workarounds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either return by value:

```
Rectangle Rectangle::Overlap(const Rectangle& rectangle);
```

which does not require to change your function body, or add an additional parameter to return the result:

```
void Rectangle::Overlap(const Rectangle& rectangle, Rectangle& out);
```

and assign the result to the out parameter.

Comment: Or do it the C way using a pointer in the second example. Sometimes it improves readability.

Answer (score 3):

Make the return type a non-reference (value). Then the returned value will be fine, using the implicit copy-constructor...

Answer (score 3):

Just change the return type to `Rectangle` (sans the reference).

Answer (score 3):

Just return a Rectangle instead of a reference to one.